# Why d3js exit().remove() don't work?

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3js, in my understanding.

```
// links is an array and id is unique key
var pathData = paths.data(links, function(d) {return d.id;});

pathData.enter().append('').attr() ...

// in there will be delete all the duplicate items
pathData.exit().remove();
```

But in my code, it recreate a node.

Here is my full code http://jsfiddle.net/yunfanyunfan/URpfB/34/

click the line, will appear many lines, because the duplicate node not removes.

Comment: But in the code you have not created any nodes.

Comment: @CyrilCherian, I create a path, it is a line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need a live copy of the paths selection. Your original code only has the initial snapshot.
2. The `.attr('d',`
   needs to be on the UPDATE+ENTER selection because the enter
   selection will be zero size since you are re-using the existing path
   each time.

```js
// set up SVG for D3
var width  = 960,
    height = 800;

var isWantToAddNode = false;
var svg = d3.select('body').select('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
var links = [{
    id:1,
    fromPoint: {x:5,y:5},
    toPoint: {x:50,y:50},
    params: 'android',
    color: '#000'
}];
var times = 0;
function initAllDef() {
    svg.select('#defs').append('svg:marker')
        .attr('id', 'arrow').attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 9)
        .attr("refY", 0)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-3L10,0L0,3")
        .attr('fill', '#000');
}

initAllDef();

// handles to link and node element groups
var paths = svg.select('#paths').selectAll('path');
var routeNodes = svg.select('#rects').selectAll('rects');


// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
    function rebuildLink() {
        //need a live selection
        var pathData = svg.select('#paths').selectAll('path').data(links, function(d){
            return d.id;
        });
        pathData.enter()
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .style('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)')
            .on('mousedown', function(d){
                times += 1;
                restart();
            });
        
        //path needs to be on update+enter
        pathData.attr('d', function(d) {
                var f = d.fromPoint, t = d.toPoint;
                return 'M' + (f.x + times * 10) + ',' + (f.y) + 'L' + t.x + ',' + t.y;
            });

        pathData.exit().remove();
    }

    rebuildLink();
}

function getStartPoint(rect) {
    return {
        x: rect.x + (rect.width>>1),
        y: rect.y + rect.height
    }
}

function getEndPoint(rect) {
    return {
        x: rect.x + (rect.width>>1),
        y: rect.y
    }
}


restart();
```

```css
svg {
    background-color: #FFF;
    /*cursor: default;*/
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
    cursor: crosshair;
}

path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    cursor: default;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

path.link.selected {
    stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
    color: blue;
    stroke: blue;
}

path.link.dragline {
    pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node {
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
    stroke: #000 !important;
    stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

rect.route-node {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

text {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
}

text.id {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <svg>
        <defs id="defs"></defs>
        <g id="paths"></g>
        <g id="rects"></g>
    </svg>        
 </body>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code you are trying to delete the line that you have created.

```
//But this is wrong way to delete.
pathData.exit().remove();
//this is the right way
svg.selectAll('path').data(pathData).exit().remove();
```

Check the updated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ktvkuhta/2/

This should give you a very good insignt on enter and exit: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Comment: This line `var pathData = paths.data(links, function(d){return d.id;});` is also incorrect, see my answer.